# Is there any workaround for installing packages ? (deepspeed error)

Tags: linux, amazon-sagemaker, apt

i was trying to use deepspeed, but when i run the training it shows an error. I have to install mpi4py using pip. However if I try to install mpi4py i get an error.
From that error i found out that to install the package, i must install "libopenmpi-dev " before, using apt. However we dont have the password to sudo. Any workaround to this ?
(or the only option is to change platforms ?)

Comment: You didn't specify how are you using Sagemaker.. I presume notebook..Why don't you just create your own container for sagemaker and install whatever you need ?

Comment: I didn't specify how am i using sagemaker cuz it doesnt matter, i was using from a terminal, but if its necessary i could use notebooks. I also cant create my own container because i dont have the required packages, and again i cannot install new packages

Comment: If you are running using docker you can probably try using the deepspeed dockerfile to build and use the image for running the code.
https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeed/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile

Comment: docker is not installed on sagemaker by default, and once again we cant install anything using apt.

Comment: I think the previours answers are correct. You can build your own docker image and use it for Sagemaker https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers.html or use an existing one extending it, install the package, add the required dependency and use it in a notebook, sagemaker studio or as an algorithm, endpoint, ... whatever fit your needs.

Comment: @DrunkKiddo97 Exactly..you don't have to install docker on a sagemaker notebook.. You have to create your own container, install whatever you want inside, push to ECR and create a training job using that container. Look at the documentation and forget about notebooks for your use case..

Comment: I think it really matters how you use sagemaker since every component has it's own way of installing packages.

Comment: if you are using a trainingjob you can use the `entry_point` script `train.py` and install the required packages using `os.system('')`. For an endpoint, you can use `inference.py`

Comment: you can also upload `requirments.txt` file and it would be installed automatically if you are using the pre-built containers by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing MPI from source?
When you don't have sudo privileges you can build from source, for MPI you can try following these installation steps from the [documentation](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/appendix.html#building-mpi)

```
tar -zxf mpich-X.X.X.tar.gz
cd mpich-X.X.X
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/mpich
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Install via apt

```
sudo apt install python3-mpi4py
```